# MySQL jobs stuck in sidekiq queue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

My Rails application takes a JSON blob of ~500 entries (from an API endpoint), throws it into a sidekiq/ redis background queue.  The background job parses the blob then loops through the entries to perform a basic Rails Model.find_or_initialize_by_field_and_field() and model.update_attributes().

If this job were in the foreground, it would take a matter of seconds (if that long).  I'm seeing these jobs remain in the sidekiq queue for 8 hours.  Obviously, something's not right.

I've recently re-tuned the MySQL database to use 75% of available RAM as the buffer_pool_size and divided that amongst 3 buffer pools.  I originally thought that might be part of the deadlock but the load avg on the box is still well below any problematic status ( 5 CPU and a load of ~ 2.5 )  At this point, I'm not convinced the DB is the problem though, of course, I can't rule it out.

I'm sure, at this point, I need to scale back the sidekiq worker instances.  In anticipation of the added load I increased the concurrency to 300 per worker (I have 2 active workers on different servers.)  Under a relatively small amount of load there queues operate as expected; even the problematic jobs are completed in ~1 minute.  Though, per the sidekiq documentation >50 concurrent workers is a bad idea.  I wasn't having any stability issues at 150 workers per instance.  The problem has been this newly introduced job that performs ~500 MySQL finds and updates.

If this were a database timeout issue, the background job should have failed and been moved from the active (busy) queue to the failed queue.  That's not the case.  They're just getting stuck in the queue.

What other either MySQL or Rails/ sidekiq tuning parameters should I be examining to ensure these jobs succeed, fail, or properly time out?

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals#ttin

Comment: Turned out the jobs weren't stuck but were long-running jobs that needed optimized.